# MongoDB Performance with Upsert

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

We are trying to make a "real time" statistics part for our application, 
and we want to use MongoDB.

So, to do this, I basically imagine a DB named **storage**. In this db, I create a **statistics** collection.

And I store my data like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55642d270528055b171fedf5"),
    "cat" : "module",
    "name" : "Injector",
    "ts_min" : ISODate("2015-05-22T13:16:00Z"),
    "nb_action" : {
        "0" : 156
    },
    "tps_action" : {
        "0" : 45016
    },
    "min_tps" : 10,
    "max_tps" : 879
}
```

So, I have a category, a name and a date to determine an unique Object. In this object, I store :

- number of used per second *(nb_action.[0..59])*
- Total time per second *(tps_action.[0..59])*
- Min time
- Max time

Now, to inject my data I use an Upsert method:

```
db.statistics.update({ 
 ts_min: ISODate("2015-05-22T13:16:00.000Z"),
 name: "Injector",
 cat: "module"
},
{
  $inc: {"nb_action.0":1, "tps_action.0":250},
  $min: {min_tps:250},
  $max: {max_tps:250}
},
{ upsert: true })
```

So, I perform 2 `$inc` to manage my counter and used `$min` and `$max` to manage my stats.

All of this works...

With 1 thread injecting 50.000 data on one single machine *(no shard)* (for 10 modules), I observe 3.000/3.500 ops per second.

And my problem is.... I can't say if it's good or not.

Any suggestions?

PS: I use long name field for the example and add a set part for initialize each second in case of insert